# Power shell get-content is too slow while performing the CSV file operation

Tags: powershell

$getErrorCodes variable has many error code.

As I want to remove the rows, wherever the error code present in the csv file.
my code is working as expected, but it is too slow, its taking around 10 min for 60000 csv transaction.

getErrorCodes = {100,101,103}

```
csv file( 3 columns)
========
 100|102|104
 110|103|109
 107|108|109
```

## Expected result:-

```
107|108|109
```

My code

```
Get-Content $CSVFile | Where-Object {($_.ToString().Split(",")[0] -notin $getErrorCodes) -and ($_.ToString().Split(",")[1] -notin $getErrorCodes)-and ($_.ToString().Split(",")[2] -notin $getErrorCodes)} | Out-File "resultfile.csv"
```

very much appreciated, if you can provide any other solution.

Comment: Try `Import-CSV` then process the resulting object and export it when done.

Comment: Import-CSV also slow, here is my code
Import-Csv $CSVFile -Header A1,A2,A3 | Where-Object {($_.A1 -notin $getErrorCodes)} | Export-Csv "aa.csv"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv)/[Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) and a [HashTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables) or [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1) which are optimized for a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm):

```
$ErrorCodes = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[String]](100,101,103)

Import-Csv $CSVFile -Header (1..3) | Where-Object {
    !($ErrorCodes.Contains($_.1)) -and
    !($ErrorCodes.Contains($_.2)) -and
    !($ErrorCodes.Contains($_.3))
} | Export-Csv .\resultfile.csv -UseQuotes Never
```

Note: if you want to remove the header from the results, you might do something like:

```
... | ConvertTo-Csv | Select-Object -skip 1 | Set-Content .\resultfile.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, am not having header in my CSV, so am getting error. i would read the file from row number1, also my file have duplicate values in the first row.
Row1 > 101 | 101 | 101
Row2 >  102 | 102 | 102
so i could not use import-csv.

Comment: What is the error? Also if you just paste the exact [mcve] (from  `-Header (1..3)` up and till `-UseQuotes Never`) I have created above? If yes, which PowerShell version are you on? FYI, the parameter `-Header (1..3)` will read a headerless csv  (and use the headers `1` to `3` instead.

Comment: I put default header as "Import-Csv $CSVFile -Delimiter ',' -Header "Letter1","Letter2","Letter3"", now it is working. Thank you so much.
Now am getting different error "Where-Object : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Property'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument
that is not null or empty, and then try the command again."
My code - Import-Csv $CSVFile -Header "Letter1","Letter2","Letter3"  | Where-Object $_."Letter1" -NotMatch $getErrorCodes | Out-File "test.csv"

Comment: Please, [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer and create a new question for any new issues.

Comment: Thanks for your timely support.

Comment: Hi @iRon , Fixed the error, Mine is not fixed csv columns, and i would compare with first column alone, but i want to display full row.

Import-Csv $CSVFile -Header col1 | Where-Object {!($getErrorCodes.Contains($_.col1)) } | Export-Csv "resultfile.csv"
Could you guide me